# Anyway to get the argument that isn't an option unix C

Tags: c, getopt

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("minimum one argument\n");
        return(1);
    } else {
        int o;
        int a = 1;
        int b = 1;

        while ((o = getopt(argc, argv, "a:b")) != -1) {
            switch (o) {
                case 'a' :
                    a = atoi(optarg);
                    break;
                case 'b' :
                    b = 0;
                    break;
                default :
                    printf("Error\n");
                    exit(1);
            }
        }
        printf("argument is %s, flag a is %d, flag b is %d\n", argv[3], a, b);
    }

}
```

This can be run these many ways. (Calling above file1.c)

```
$ gcc -Wall file1.c
$ ./a.out -a14 10
argument is 10, flag a is 14, flag b is 1
```

also

```
$ ./a.out -b 12
argument is 12, flag a is 1, flag b is 0
```

also

```
$ ./a.out 12
argument is 12, flag a is 1, flag b is 1
```

also

```
$ ./a.out -b -a12 15
argument is 15, flag a is 12, flag b is 0
```

How do I get the index position of the argument that isn't an option also get all these to work as intended above?

Comment: Isn't `optind` your need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `getopt()` function ([GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt) or [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html)) returns `-1` (and not `EOF`) when it has finished processing options.  The global variable `optind` is the index of the first argument that was not consumed by the option processing.

Therefore, when `getopt()` returns `-1`, `argv[optind]` contains a pointer to the non-option argument if it is not null (or, equivalently, if `optind < argc`).

Comment: Can also be found as the `4th` paragraph in [`man 3 getopt`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) (although one could argue that JL's explanation is a bit more palatable)